# Confirm Form Resubmission on browser popup duplicates the record

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback

I am developing an application in which their exist a problem. When i click on to submit button, the data is inserted into db. But when i press ctrl+R or f5 a chrome or IE pop up occurs which says Confirm Form Resubmission. when i click continue then the record is duplicated into database.

My question is,

1. Why is this popup occuring? because of the postback? if because of postback then do my code have any issues or it occurs with every body when doing postback.
2. Will using mvc will solve this issue completely?

My code:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Page.IsValid)
            {
                paramArray = new string[9];
                paramValues = new object[9];
                try
                {
                    paramArray[0] = "@AccountNumber";
                    paramValues[0] = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.txtAccountNumber.Value) ? this.txtAccountNumber.Value.Trim() : string.Empty);

                    paramArray[1] = "@OpeningBalance";
                    paramValues[1] = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.txtOpeningBalance.Value) ? Convert.ToDouble(this.txtOpeningBalance.Value.Trim()) : 0.00);

                    paramArray[2] = "@ClosingBalance";
                    paramValues[2] = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.txtClosingBalance.Value) ? Convert.ToDouble(this.txtClosingBalance.Value.Trim()) : 0.00);

                    paramArray[3] = "@PaymentMode";
                    paramValues[3] = this.ddlModeofPayment.Value;

                    paramArray[4] = "@PaymentDate";
                    paramValues[4] = this.dtPaymentDate.Value;

                    paramArray[5] = "@PaymentAmount";
                    paramValues[5] = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.txtPaymentAmount.Value) ? Convert.ToDouble(this.txtPaymentAmount.Value.Trim()) : 0.00);

                    paramArray[6] = "@isAccount";
                    paramValues[6] = true;

                    paramArray[7] = "@UserId";
                    paramValues[7] = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.User.Identity.Name.Remove(0, 7)) ? this.User.Identity.Name.Remove(0, 7) : string.Empty);

                    paramArray[8] = "@isProcessed";
                    paramValues[8] = default(bool);

                    var success = herlperUtility.ExecuteParameterizedQuery("{CALL asp_sp_InsertPayment(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}", paramArray, paramValues);

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(success.Rows[0]["ReferenceNumber"].ToString()))
                    {
                        this.Page.Response.Redirect("AccountPaymentScreen.aspx?flag=1");
                        divSuccess.Attributes.Add("style", "display:block");
                        this.refId.InnerText = "<b>Success!</b> The " + success.Rows[0]["ReferenceNumber"] + " has been successfuly forwarded to the supervisor";

                        this.ClearFields();
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        this.divFailure.Attributes.Add("style", "display:block");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    this.divFailure.Attributes.Add("style", "display:block");
                    this.divFailure.InnerText = ex.Message;
                }
            }
```

Comment: 1. yes to first part 2. possibly, mvc also helps with data handling a lot more than plain asp (it is also easier to edit in my opinion)

Comment: for mvc http://sampathloku.blogspot.in/2013/05/how-to-use-prg-pattern-with-aspnet-mvc-4.html

Answer (score 2):

The solution to this is to follow the [Post-Redirect-Get pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).  This means that after an HTTP POST in which you do some kind of transactional activity you redirect the client to an HTTP GET.

In a very simplistic way of thinking:  GET should not modify anything, while POST is there to make changes.

For example, consider the following workflow.

1. The user presses submit on an shopping cart page (HTTP POST).
2. You validate that a credit card is valid and if so charge the
   account and set your warehouse activities in motion
3. You show a screen confirming the order.

If everything goes well and you haven't redirected the client (e.g., you show a panel with a success message and hide the cart) and the client presses refresh, the order will be resubmitted which is probably not ideal for anyone other than accounts receivable.

Following the PRG pattern, after submitting the order you would redirect to a GET page (possibly with the order id in the query string so you have some way of referencing the order) and show your success message.  This page can be refreshed as many times as the customer wants (with the added bonus of being bookmarkable) with no side-effects to your back end system or the customer's wallet.

It's worth noting that you don't have to be fanatical about this.  In this example if the credit card validation failed you could choose to just display the results of the POST action and toggle an error message on your page.  If the user refreshes the page, the validation will run and fail again but no changes will be made to your back end system.

As for MVC - It's not so much that it's easier to accomplish this (it is), it's that you end up thinking about these kinds of things a little more than when using WebForms which (for better or worse) hides these concepts behind an abstraction.

Comment: That is not a solution, it is a circumvention.  Businesses don't ask for this type of kludge, they want straight posts.  It is pretty amazing that the browser kings feel they have to assume developers don't know how to do their job.

Comment: My apologies if I misunderstood you, but I don't see how this isn't a solution?  Browsers display the html that is returned as a result of a POST command and assume that if you hit refresh you are asking for the exact same action to occur.  No one is saying anything about no doing stright POSTs, but rather what to after that action is complete.  Post-Redirect-Get is a well known pattern for handling this.

Comment: Ok thanks Joe, no worries, I'm just seeing this from a programmer's perspective, assume for a second that the first post was indeed completed.  Anything inserted into DB should have a Unique ID that should be returned as a part of the confirmation.  If the post happens twice, and there's confirmation there, then the program should do nothing.  That's all I'm saying... when the browser decides whats best we wind up with clicking through nonsense when developing things. IMO...

Comment: Actually if a post is committed to the DB the user should not be shown the form until they reset the browser state. PRG is IMO a circumvention to a poor design, but maybe not, please explain.